# Convert table to JSON omitting repeated header lines

Tags: json, apache-kafka, jq

I have a Kafka command which will give you an output in below format.

```
GROUP                         TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
connect-mm-leads-mapture-map DEV.mmvm.V2 0          9               9               0               connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0-296b0e23-0995-4220-b493-fb006f41760a /10.00.000.00   connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0
connect-mm-leads-mapture-map DEV.mmLeads.V1 1          7               7               0               connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0-296b0e23-0995-4220-b493-fb006f41760a /10.01.01.01   connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0
GROUP             TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                         HOST            CLIENT-ID
connect-ccc-7562w DEV3.MMAutoshipTemplates.V1    0          594013          594021          8               connector-consumer-kkk-34ff-0-dfsfdsf-dsfd-1 /10.01.01.02   connector-consumer-ccc-7562w-0
connect-ccc-7562w DEV3.MMProducts.V1             0          4884            4885            1               connector-consumer-kkk-234f-2444vf-2-s-dsffdd-11 /10.01.01.03   connector-consumer-ccc-7562w-0
connect-kkk-7562w DEV3.mmLeads.V1
GROUP                              TOPIC              PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                                                                          HOST            CLIENT-ID
_company-centerpart-0-command _company-command 0          20              20              0               _company-centerpart-0-command-0d76f6e2-7ff3-47fa-a63c-0f36aedda046-StreamThread-1-consumer-66e0cc27-469e-4735-80cf-c930f27f6e5e /10.01.01.04   _company-centerpart-0-command-0d76f6e2-7ff3-47fa-a63c-0f36aedda046-StreamThread-1-consumer
```

But I want the output in Json format and the content should come as below.

Desired Output should be :

```
[
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-mm-leads-mapture-map",
   "TOPIC": "DEV.mmvm.V2",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "9",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "9",
   "LAG": "0",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0-296b0e23-0995-4220-b493-fb006f41760a",
   "HOST": "/10.00.000.00",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-mm-leads-mapture-map",
   "TOPIC": "DEV.mmLeads.V1",
   "PARTITION": "1",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "7",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "7",
   "LAG": "0",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0-296b0e23-0995-4220-b493-fb006f41760a",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.01",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-ccc-7562w",
   "TOPIC": "DEV3.MMAutoshipTemplates.V1",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "594013",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "594021",
   "LAG": "8",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-kkk-34ff-0-dfsfdsf-dsfd-1",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.02",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-ccc-7562w-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-ccc-7562w",
   "TOPIC": "DEV3.MMProducts.V1",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "4884",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "4885",
   "LAG": "1",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-kkk-234f-2444vf-2-s-dsffdd-11",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.03",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-ccc-7562w-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-kkk-7562w",
   "TOPIC": "DEV3.mmLeads.V1",
   "PARTITION": "",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "",
   "LAG": "",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "",
   "HOST": "",
   "CLIENT-ID": ""
 },

 {
   "GROUP": "_company-centerpart-0-command",
   "TOPIC": "_company-command",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "20",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "20",
   "LAG": "0",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "_company-centerpart-0-command-0d76f6e2-7ff3-47fa-a63c-0f36aedda046-StreamThread-1-consumer-66e0cc27-469e-4735-80cf-c930f27f6e5e",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.04",
   "CLIENT-ID": "_company-centerpart-0-command-0d76f6e2-7ff3-47fa-a63c-0f36aedda046-StreamThread-1-consumer"
 }
]
```

I am using below command and able to convert into expected json with some additional meaning less data.

Command :

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server "xxxxxxx:9092" --command-config /root/config.properties --describe --all-groups| jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]] | .[1] as $header | .[2:] | [.[] | [. as $x | range($header | length) | {"key": $header[.], "value": $x[.]}] | from_entries]'
```

Command output :

```
[
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-mm-leads-mapture-map",
   "TOPIC": "DEV.mmvm.V2",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "9",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "9",
   "LAG": "0",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0-296b0e23-0995-4220-b493-fb006f41760a",
   "HOST": "/10.00.000.00",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-mm-leads-mapture-map",
   "TOPIC": "DEV.mmLeads.V1",
   "PARTITION": "1",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "7",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "7",
   "LAG": "0",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0-296b0e23-0995-4220-b493-fb006f41760a",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.01",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-mm-leads-mapture-map-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "GROUP",
   "TOPIC": "TOPIC",
   "PARTITION": "PARTITION",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "CURRENT-OFFSET",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "LOG-END-OFFSET",
   "LAG": "LAG",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "CONSUMER-ID",
   "HOST": "HOST",
   "CLIENT-ID": "CLIENT-ID"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-ccc-7562w",
   "TOPIC": "DEV3.MMAutoshipTemplates.V1",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "594013",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "594021",
   "LAG": "8",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-kkk-34ff-0-dfsfdsf-dsfd-1",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.02",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-ccc-7562w-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-ccc-7562w",
   "TOPIC": "DEV3.MMProducts.V1",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "4884",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "4885",
   "LAG": "1",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "connector-consumer-kkk-234f-2444vf-2-s-dsffdd-11",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.03",
   "CLIENT-ID": "connector-consumer-ccc-7562w-0"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "connect-kkk-7562w",
   "TOPIC": "DEV3.mmLeads.V1",
   "PARTITION": "",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "",
   "LAG": "",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "",
   "HOST": "",
   "CLIENT-ID": ""
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "GROUP",
   "TOPIC": "TOPIC",
   "PARTITION": "PARTITION",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "CURRENT-OFFSET",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "LOG-END-OFFSET",
   "LAG": "LAG",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "CONSUMER-ID",
   "HOST": "HOST",
   "CLIENT-ID": "CLIENT-ID"
 },
 {
   "GROUP": "_company-centerpart-0-command",
   "TOPIC": "_company-command",
   "PARTITION": "0",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "20",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "20",
   "LAG": "0",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "_company-centerpart-0-command-0d76f6e2-7ff3-47fa-a63c-0f36aedda046-StreamThread-1-consumer-66e0cc27-469e-4735-80cf-c930f27f6e5e",
   "HOST": "/10.01.01.04",
   "CLIENT-ID": "_company-centerpart-0-command-0d76f6e2-7ff3-47fa-a63c-0f36aedda046-StreamThread-1-consumer"
 }
]
```

Seeing below meaning less (unwanted) output which should be removed :

```
{
   "GROUP": "GROUP",
   "TOPIC": "TOPIC",
   "PARTITION": "PARTITION",
   "CURRENT-OFFSET": "CURRENT-OFFSET",
   "LOG-END-OFFSET": "LOG-END-OFFSET",
   "LAG": "LAG",
   "CONSUMER-ID": "CONSUMER-ID",
   "HOST": "HOST",
   "CLIENT-ID": "CLIENT-ID"
 },
```

Note : Command output may have many lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pair corresponding elements of two arrays and construct an object out of them, we use the `transpose` built-in in conjunction with `add`.

And slurping raw input into a huge single JSON script is often unnecessary, not to mention how bad a practice it is.

Given `--null-input` and `--raw-input` options on the command line, this JQ program produces your expected output:

```
[ input | splits(" +") ] as $header | [
  inputs
  | [ splits(" +") ]
  | select(. != $header)
  | [ $header, . ]
  | [ transpose[] | { (.[0]): .[1] } ]
  | add
]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LEuZ-EoYRo)</sup>